# @uniswap SDK -- how do I figure out the best route for a SWAP? How do do multihop with SDK?

Tags: uniswap

I'm calling UNISWAP SDK to price a trade on pair like USDC, PAX and getting significantly worse results than the UX:

```
const sourceToken = new Token(ChainId.MAINNET, source_token_address, source_token_decimals);
const sourceAmount = new TokenAmount(sourceToken, source_amount);

output_amount = await uniswap_token_pair.getOutputAmount(sourceAmount);

const final_output_val = web3.utils.toBN(output_amount[0].raw.toString());

console.log(`UNISWAP output ${pair_name} raw= ${output_amount[0].raw.toString()} num=${bn_to_number(final_output_val, target_token_decimals)}`);

return final_output_val;
```

I'm assuming that it's because the WebSite chooses a multi-hop route USDC=>ETH=>PAX. How do I do this in the SDK without having to myself explictily craft the route -- i.e I basically want it to figure out the best route from me just like the web site does? I can't see a param anywhere to have the SDK do a multihop.?

Comment: I have no idea about this myself, but tracing the HTTP requests made in the UI, it calls a contract called `multicall` with all the LPs of existing tokens. My idea is they maintain a database of all pairs, and then use the multicall contract to get every price of every LP for said token.

Comment: @bru53001 do you have an address for the multicall Contract ?

Comment: You can find it [here.](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5ba1e12693dc8f9c48aad8770482f4739beed696#code)

Answer (score 5):

```
Trade.bestTradeExactIn(
    pairs: Pair[],
    amountIn: TokenAmount,
    tokenOut: Token,
    { maxNumResults = 3, maxHops = 3 }: BestTradeOptions = {}): Trade[]
```

> Given a list of pairs, a fixed amount in, and token amount out, this method returns the best maxNumResults trades that swap an input token amount to an output token, making at most maxHops hops. The returned trades are sorted by output amount, in decreasing order, and all share the given input amount.

ref: https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/2.0.0/reference/trade#besttradeexactin